# What are the pro's and cons of GST (goods and service tax) ? And what influence it can make in the Indian economy?

Tags: financial-economics, international-economics, political-economy

As government is planning to introduce GST in India, what change it will make in India's economy?

GST is introduced in many countries except American, so why American has not introduce GST yet?